# Birthdays employee Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with employees data, name, photo, date of birth and etc.

I'm trying to create a url that shows the birthdays of the employees where I can filter, if i click at one button, filter the birthdays of the day, another button, birthdays of the week and so on.

I'm don't know where I can work with the date of birth to generate theses "category".

I'm looking for ideas to implement these

Thanks in advance

Comment: FWIW some birthday-related HR systems tend to show the month and day but not the year.  For privacy/security reasons:  knowing it isnt really needed to wish Joe and Jane a happy birthday.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i have some applications on an intranet, the idea was to add this info, its a small company so we dont have HR systems for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ask,

> ... where I can work with the date of birth to generate theses 'category'

it sounds like you're asking about a *view*.  Views are Python functions typically placed in a file called `views.py`.

Let's say you have a model `Employee` defined in your `models.py` with a field `birthdate` (among others):

```
# models.py

class Employee(models.Model):

    employee = models.CharField(
        help_text = 'Employee name'
    )
    birthdate = models.DateField(
        help_text = "Employee's birthdate"
    )
    # other fields...
```

I'll further assume that you've run `makemigrations` and `migrate` on this model so that it has a table in your database (more on [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/)).  And of course, this won't work in the end unless you put actual data into that database, which is also covered in the docs.

Then in your `views.py` file, you can import this model and access its fields using code like

```
# views.py
from yourApp.models import Employee

def bday(request):

    employees = Employee.objects.all()
    for emp in employees:
        bdate = emp.birthdate
        # further logic with 'bdate', etc.
```

The docs have [much more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/) on how to access your data in view functions.

Once your view has loaded all of the data you'll want to display on the page, you'll combine that data with a [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/) and use the URLconf settings in your `urls.py` file to map the `bday()` view function to whatever URL you want.

The interactivity you mention for applying filters would typically be done using JavaScript, otherwise you'll have to reload the page entirely every time the user changes a filter.  That JavaScript would be written in a separate file and included in your template.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/) are imperfect, but they'll certainly help you get a better idea of what you're looking for.  In particular, I recommend the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/), which you should work through, and the basics of [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/views/)

Comment: Nice, I got the idea, I started with Django last week, I just know how to work with basic views, like get data from a form and things like that. I'm learning model now. I still dont know how to work with the model data                                                                         
Thanks for the tips